# Logarithmic equation (basic)

Tags: logarithms, self-learning

I am stuck on how to solve this equation

My solution which I will post below is $10^{42}$

But the correct answer should be $42$.

$$7\log{x}-2\log{x^3}=42$$
$$7\log{x}-6\log{x}=42$$
$$\log{x}=42$$
$$x=10^{42}$$

Comment: Petra , Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions. Also your solution is correct. Maybe the book has a typo.

Comment: Isn't the equation $\log x-2\log x^3=\log 42$ ?

Comment: Is $\lg$ suppose to be base 2?  or the natural log or what?

Comment: No it’s. “… =42“

Comment: It’s to the basis of ten

Comment: I see nothing wrong here, so either you copied the question wrong or the answer sheet is wrong.

Comment: Well the book is wrong  $7 \log x-2\log x^3 = \log x$.  so you have $\log x = 42$.  It's probably just a typo.

Comment: Thanks I’m so glad, I’m working on some competence sheets(basic requirements needed for a degree I will start).  They do a test before and you are only allowed to get one out of 50 wrong in order to continue, so I got really worried when I could not solve the equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine, as an "alternative" to check

$$7\log{x}-2\log{x^3}=42\iff \frac73\log{x^3}-2\log{x^3}=\frac13\log x^3=42\iff \log x = 42$$

probably there is a typo in the book.

Comment: Thanks you so much, that help a lot

Comment: @Petra You are welcome! Bye